# How to keep a querystring parameter in subsequent requests in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application I want to use some parameters to "survive" several subsequent requests irrespective of whether they were processed in controller or not.

For example, if the request has `order/add/1234?promocode=new2014` in it, I want it to stay all the way the user puts together his or her order until he proceeds to check-out. This means, that every action link generated using HTML helpers in my views should contain this parameter.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This would be a good use of the Session, in my opinion. If the parameter is there, make note of it in the Session. Then clear it out once check out is done.

Comment: The best approach would be to write custom ActionLink helpers that will preserve query string values when generating the url.

Comment: @CharlieKilian You are perfectly right, but I want a stateless application and do not depend upon the session that might expire...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Is this the only approach? Can't I add a parameter in an ActionFilter that is automatically taken into account by default helpers?

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin, no, it's not the only approach. You always have the possibility of using stateful approaches with Session as suggested earlier. But this is the best approach. And, no, ActionFilters cannot help if you are unable to generate proper urls in your views.

Answer (score 1):

You could save this parameter in Viewbag and then use it again like

@Url.Action("index",new {promocode = Viewbag.CurrentPromocode})

Comment: This means I need to change all `@Url.Action()` calls in all my views. And I want to keep any potential parameter, not a specific one.

Comment: what I think(and know for right now) is you need some kind of persistence store. Even if you would write your own actionfilterattribue and override action helper you need to store it somewhere for the time..
so sessions or maybe a workflow ?

Comment: No, you don't need any persistence store for that. This would make your application stateful which is the worst enemy of scalability. What he needs is a trivial custom HTML helper that will generate the proper url, taking into account query string parameters that are already present in the current url. Also with this approach you get great SEO capabilities and a possibility to bookmark your urls.

Comment: so it looks like all he needs is some action filter with saving desired parameters to Viewbag and then html helper taking all needed parameters and setting RouteValueDictionary with existing parameters saved earlier in the Viewbag and return actual ActionLink HtmlHelper with arguments passed to his new helper. 
Which I think is pretty the same solution as one in my answer but done in more 'automatic' way